# Adding combine arrays only if value doesn't already exist

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

If I were to have the strings:

```
string s1 = "abcabb";
string S2 = "acbcba";
```

And wanted to add them in away that the result would be:

`string s[] = ["aa","bc", "ac", "bb", "ba"]`

Combining chars based on index but only adding to s[] if the pair doesn't exist eg `"ba" = "ab"` adding +1 to an integer if a duplicate is found.

What could be a decently fast algorithm or function to do so for large strings with max size 10⁶.

Comment: *"but only adding to s[] if the pair doesn't exist eg "ba" = "ab" adding +1 to an integer if a duplicate is found."* What you are looking for is usually called a **multiset**. See for instance https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/

Comment: Oh I didn't know those existed. I will look into that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `std::unordered_map` to add the `std::string` keys and an `int` as the value storing how many of that key exists. You might want to make sure that `'a' 'b'` and `'b' 'a'` both end up as the same key.

Example:

```cpp
std::string s1 = "abcabb";
std::string s2 = "acbcba";

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> result;

for (size_t index = 0; index < s1.size(); ++index) {
    char c1 = s1[index];
    char c2 = s2[index];
    std::string key = c1 < c2 ? std::string({c1, c2}) : std::string({c2, c1});
    ++result[key];
}
```

This should be in O(n) time since the lookup in the `std::unordered_map` is constant time.
Note that this code assumes that both input strings have the same length.

Comment: You could add a simple check that both strings have the same length, before the `for`-loop.